# Can't require node modules in JS files in svelte electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, commonjs, svelte

I'm using electron with svelte as my frontend framework.

I have JS files that contain functions used by my svelte components.

When I try to import a node module using `require` - it returns an empty object.
When I use `require` inside a svelte component it works fine. (I've set `nodeIntegration: true` in my electron.js file).

How could I fix this?

**EDIT:** An example:

```html
<!--SvelteComponent.svelte-->
<script>
  import {func} from "./jsFile";
</script>
```

```
//jsFile.js
const fs = require("fs"); // This require returns an empty object
export function func {...}
```

I also get a Rollup warning: `(!) Plugin node-resolve: preferring built-in module 'fs' over local alternative at 'fs', pass 'preferBuiltins: false' to disable this behavior or 'preferBuiltins: true' to disable this warning`

Comment: I use svelte with electron and can require in all I need. Please show an example of a failing import, if possible with a well-known library and we can have a look.

Comment: Use the starter pack : https://github.com/nateshmbhat/svelte-electron-ts-starter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I should have used `window.require` instead of `require`

Answer (score -1):

Here's a fragment of a working svelte component from my application. All imported or required objects just work fine.

```
<script>
    import '../../../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css';
    import '../../../css/material-icons-svelte.css';  // we'd have to adjust the font paths!! check extra.css
    import '../../../node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css';
    import '../../../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js';

    const {getState, getStore} = require('../../../dist/store/store.renderer');
    const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');
    const _ = require('lodash');
```

Edit

I added this to my `App.svelte` component, that I use on a svelte app with electron and, well, it works. Prints the `fs` object to the console and it's not empty

```
    const fs = require('fs')
    console.log(fs);
```

`nodeIntegration` is set to true, this my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width'>

    <link rel='stylesheet' href='../../../css/global.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='../../../dist/app/myapp/extra.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='../../../dist/app/myapp/bundle.css'>
</head>

<body class="grey lighten-4">
    <script src='../../../dist/app/myapp/bundle.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And I'm on electron 8.2.5

Comment: I have added an example

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but the problem I have occures when using require in JS files, imported by a Svelte component, not in the component itself

Comment: You seem to have two different problems: one is `fs`. With nodeIntegration properly enabled you should be able to open the devTools an electron webwindow and write that on the console: `window.require('fs')`. That should not be empty. Otherwise there's some mistake with the BrowserWindow configuration.